# Rspec is calling the original method instead of the mock

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an issue with rspec whereby an external object is created from within a method, and instead of using the mock of that object, the actual object is created.

Ruby code:

```
module A
  class B
    def initialize
      @my_variable = function_call
    end

    private

    def function_call
      external_object = ExternalObject.new(123)
      {
        key1: external_object.external_method.to_s,
        key2: external_object.to_s
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec:

```
describe A:B do

  let(:mock_external_obj) { 'mock_ext_obj' }
  let(:mock_external_obj_to_s) { 'mock_ext_obj_to_str' }

  before do
    allow(ExternalObject).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_external_obj)
    allow(mock_external_obj).to receive(:to_string).and_return(mock_external_obj_to_s)
    allow(mock_external_obj).to receive(:external_method).and_return(my_variable)
  end

  subject { described_class.new }

  context 'does something' do
    it 'does something else' do
      expect(subject.my_variable).to eq({
                                         key1: mock_external_obj_to_s,
                                         key2: mock_external_obj_to_s
                                       })
    end
  end
end
```

In the example above, I would expect `ExternalObject.new(123)` to return `mock_external_obj`. Instead, it is actually calling `ExternalObject.new(123)` and `external_object.external_method.to_s` calls the actual external object's methods.

Comment: Try to run it with `allow(ExternalObject).to receive(:new).with(anything).and_return(mock_external_obj)`. Does it fix it?

Comment: No it doesn't, unfortunately

Comment: OK. Try to pass `A::ExternalObject` to the `allow` method. If it still doesn't work, call `::ExternalObject` in your `function_call` method from `B` class and pass `::ExternalObject` to the `allow` method (put two colons before the class name).